# Allow larger elements to push down and move other elements out of the way without leaving spaces

Tags: css, css-float, multiple-columns, flexbox

While attempting to make an 'image wall' of sorts, with differing sizes of images, it's proven difficult to leave no gaps.

Ideally, larger images should push images to both sides, not allowing any gaps to form on the left, which seems to happen at the moment.

Examples, that I have created, exist here: http://codepen.io/Smashman/pen/LbydF

```
.flex
  display: flex
  flex-wrap: wrap
  align-items: flex-start

.float
  & .item
    float: left

.column
  +column-count(3)
  +column-gap(0)
```

Flex, Float and Column are the attempts shown here and so far, float is the closest.

Flex doesn't allow the same area to be occupied if already pushed down and column completely reorders the content and resizes elements at will.

In this example, 4 would, ideally, be directly below 1 and then 5 is below 3. This would allow the wall to exist without gaps.

If someone could help me, I greatly would appreciate it.

Thank you.

Comment: I don't think you'll be able to do what you're looking to do without some serious JS finessing and number crunching, or hardcoding it.

Comment: I agree with @Benjamin.I've tried this SEVERAL different ways, but in the current development stages of flexbox, I just don't think it's possible. This sort of thing should be relatively easy using some JS though. Here's a [jQuery plugin](http://www.wookmark.com/jquery-plugin) I found that maybe in the direction you're wanting to go.